# Creating an instance of generic class using a type reflected from an assembly

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a class like below which has some methods on it.

```
class RepositoryManager<T> where T: IEntity
```

What I would like to do, is go through all the types in my assembly that implement IEntity and create a version of RepositoryManager for each of those types. I can read all types in my assembly that implement IEntity through reflection.

1) But using those types, how do I create an instance of RepositoryManager for each of those types?

2) How do I invoke a method on one of those created instances if they are not strongly typed?

Comment: thanks, I've added a part 2 of the question -  How do I invoke a method on one of those created instances?

Comment: You really should not ask 2 questions in one... When you transform your second part into separate question please make sure to add sample code - it is very unclear what you mean "they are not strongly typed".